# Can personal requests be made during the mussaf of rosh hodesh or chol hamoed?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, musaf, chol-weekday, personal-request-bakashot

On a holiday it is forbidden to make a personal request. Does this same prohibition apply to the mussaf of rosh hodesh and hol hamoed when all the regular shemonah esrei bakashot are left out?

Comment: Why would you think that is the case? During the Amida before and after you can, so what changes during the 5 minutes of Mussaf?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I think that the question would be that there is no place in the musaf to insert bakashot while there is a place (Shma Koleinu as an example) in Shacharis. I would suppose that this would make a difference. Since this is logic only (with no source) I am leaving this a comment.

Comment: @sabbahillel There's still the paragraph _Elokai netzor_

Comment: @Daniel Do people add to it in the same way they add to Shma Koleinu or Refaeinu?

Comment: @sabbahillel I don't know what "people" do, but I was taught that only short teffilot should be added to the _berakhot_ themselves and longer-form requests as well as requests that don't fit nicely into the categories outlined within the _berakhot_ could be added to _Elokai netzor_

Comment: @sabbahillel - the entire last paragraph of the 4th bracha is full of _requests_, so why not add more?

Comment: @DannySchoemann, which 4th bracha are you referring to? Sim Shalom?

Comment: No. That's the 6th bracha. 4th ends with these _requests_: חַדֵּשׁ עָלֵינוּ אֶת הַחֹדֶשׁ הַזֶּה לְטוֹבָה וְלִבְרָכָה, לְשָׂשׂוֹן וּלְשִׂמְחָה, לִישׁוּעָה וּלְנֶחָמָה, לְפַרְנָסָה וּלְכַלְכָּלָה, לְחַיִּים טוֹבִים וּלְשָׁלוֹם, לִמְחִילַת חֵטְא, וְלִסְלִיחַת עָוֹן OR אֶת בִּרְכַּת מוֹעֲדֶיךָ. לְחַיִּים טוֹבִים וּלְשָׁלוֹם. לְשִׂמְחָה וּלְשָׂשׂוֹן. כַּאֲשֶׁר רָצִיתָ וְאָמַרְתָּ לְבָרְכֵנוּ:  קַדְּשֵׁנוּ בְּמִצְוֹתֶיךָ וְתֵן חֶלְקֵנוּ בְּתוֹרָתֶךָ שַׂבְּעֵנוּ מִטּוּבֶךָ וְשַׂמַּח נַפְשֵׁנוּ בִּישׁוּעָתֶךָ. וְטַהֵר לִבֵּנוּ לְעָבְדְּךָ בֶּאֱמֶת.

Comment: @DannySchoemann : _why not add more?_ Why not make up your שמונה עשרה?

Comment: @user4736 - You can't make up your own Sh.Es. because you have to follow the template instituted by Chazal.